# Chrome Dev Tools - can I always have pretty print enabled?

Tags: google-chrome, pretty-print

As part of our build the code is minimised I'm currently debugging some js and constantly have to click the pretty print button in chrome dev tools. Is there a way to permanently enable pretty printing in chrome dev tools ?

Comment: +1 let me know if you find the solution

Comment: @AbhijitGaikwad, see the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371293/chrome-dev-tools-can-i-always-have-pretty-print-enabled#answer-59254822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible yet. The way that I do is that I manage it through the build process to not minify the CSS and JS.

Comment: It's not actual now. Check the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59254822/9205802) below.

Answer (score 40):

## Yes!

This has become available:

In Dev Tools:  `⋮` > `Settings` (<kbd>F1</kbd>) > `Experiments` > `Automatically pretty print in the Sources Panel`.

[image]

Comment: enabling flag may not be needed at all.

Comment: @T.Todua is correct - In Chrome 95, I was able to find the option in Dev Tools > Settings > Experiments > Automatically Pretty print.. without the need to enable any flag.

Comment: Now we need also another option for automatically prettifying json data such as the ones in the Response sub-tab of the Network tab.

Comment: I think people mean the network response, not Sources.